# android listView how to modify scrollbar color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollbar, android-scrollbar

I want to change color of my scrollbars in listviews.

First I added in the theme:

```
<item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/myscrollbar</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/myscrollbar</item>
```

Next I created drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#FF9900" android:startColor="#FF9900"/> 
    <corners android:radius="1dp" /> 
    <size android:width="3dp" /> 
</shape>
```

And it doesnt work. Instead of scrollbar I get the line of the given color from the top until the bottom of the screen (it's not scrollable, it doesn't show the current position, just a long line but in my selected color).

Any solution?

Comment: Add info android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18", app with ViewPager (v4).